# Link_to in rails and dynamic names from modal#show

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, loops, hyperlink, erb

I have a loop that creates a list of works from the modal `work`

//does work but want test to be <%= work. name %>

```
<ol class="meny-control mobile"> 
   <% @works.each do |work| %>
       <li class="" data-id="<%= work.id %>"><%= link_to 'test', work %></li>
   <% end %>
</ol>
```

//doesnt work but want it to

```
<ol class="meny-control mobile"> 
       <% @works.each do |work| %>
           <li class="" data-id="<%= work.id %>"><%= link_to '<%= work.name %>', work %></li>
       <% end %>
    </ol>
```

As you would guess the `<%= work.name %>` throws a syntax error.   How do I correctly format the `link_to` to display each `work.name` as the 'path' && the  anchor's inner html as `work.name`.

Being new to rails, I'm still really iffy on understanding documentation properly.  Could you please reference from [link_to()](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) (if even there) where this format is explained so I use this for future referencing & understanding --also how to properly edit the stack question title for future similar question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is because of the nesting of `<%` tags and I suppose you already are aware of that.  To solve your problem use the following:

```
<%= link_to "#{work.name}", work %>
```

The `#{}` is used to interpolate variables, i.e. replacing variables with their values within the string literals as in `link_to "#{work.name}"` above where `work.name` will be replaced by the value `work.name` holds.

Comment: what is that syntax called?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood, I've added a line in my answer to answer your comment.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need `"#{}"`.

you can write this:`<%= link_to work.name, work %>`